# Pentaho Data Integration Kettle - Why when one record is updated it appears as if two records are updated?

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho Data Integration Kettle and SQL Server and have already made a Data Warehouse, but there is something I don't understand. When I update a record on a dimension it appears as if two records were updated, although it only updated one as it should.

First I extract from CSV file, then select and rename values, then look up for another dimension surrogate key and then lookup/update dimension with punch through. (SCD Type 1)

[image: Pentaho ETL transformation]

After updating just 1 record:

[image: Pentaho duplicate in Log]

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your last Dimension L/U step doing a "punch through" update? If so, then any row of data from the main stream can trigger multiple updates on the dimension table.

Comment: Yes it is doing a punch trough. Why does that happen? Still don´t understand

Comment: In a punch through, ALL versions of the record will be updated if an attribute changes. So, if you already have v1 and v2 on the table and a new version occurs, both rows will be updated on the DB; the count of updated rows refers to the number of DB updates, not the number of rows of data in your data stream.

Comment: Nsousa yes if there are 2 versions that will happen, but thats not the case. There is only 1 version of all records on that table. In fact, punch through is used to overwrite the record, so what you are saying still doesn't explain why there are 2 updated rows.

Comment: and only 1 row of data triggers an update? No two records there? clearly PDI is telling you there were two rows updated in the database. You may want to look into a more verbose log level to understand what PDI is doing, but you have plenty of information here to drive your investigation.